# Why my pixels are not clipped against near/far planes

Tags: directx, directx-10

I have a really weird problem. I render some triangles in the scene with D3D10 and what is surprising is that color values of these pixels are not clipped against near/far planes. On the other hand, depth values seem to be clipped fine. Evidence that this works as I have just described is as following:

- when I render objects in the z-range that is "within" view frustum, everything is fine
- when one object is inside the z-range and one is in front of it (between camera's eye and near plane), the objects inside the z-range "shines thhrough" the object that is closer. So z-buffering is working perfectly fine
- I also checked output VS vertices values; all vertices that are outside the z-range and should be clipped (and they are in the z-buffer but are not in the color buffer) have their Z/W values outside [0, 1] interval

Idea idea what could be wrong? I think it might be some render state set incorrectly but I don't really know where to look.

Comment: Pictures and relevant code extracts are highly appreciated.

Comment: http://maxest.fm.interii.pl/fine.jpgall objects are in the view frustum's z-range

http://maxest.fm.interii.pl/bad.jpg all objects are in front of the near plane

As you can see, the first picture is correct, where the second case clearly shows all pixels rendered without any z-testing

Comment: This is getting very, very weird. I've just established that clipping (of only color pixels!, again, Z-buffer works fine) to the near plane turns off when I set my own custom rasterizer state, and clipping to the far plane turns off when I additionaly set my own custom depthstencil state. What the heck?

Comment: FOUND IT! Ehh... Turned out I forgot to set DepthClipEnable to true (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I always call ZeroMemory on D3D structures and set by hand *all* variables of the structure. In this case I simply omitted one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making your comment an answer, as it was exactly the issue I had in D3D11 (same in D3D10).

Make sure that you set `DepthClipEnable` to `TRUE` in any [`D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11_1/ns-d3d11_1-cd3d11_rasterizer_desc1) in question.